# Disabling DataAnnotations Validation (and keep the DB rules)

Tags: c#, data-annotations

My question is: Is it possible to disable the validation aspect of DataAnnotations? and keep the rules they apply to the table in the DB?

**Example**

If I have:

```
[Required]
public string Name {get;set;}
```

It will apply the `nullable=false` to the property in the table.

So I'm using FluentValidation but I can't keep the DataAnnotation and keep the `nullable=false` because if I keep the `[Required]` it throws:

> Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be
>   unique. The following validation type was seen more than once:
>   required

Can't I disable the validation aspect and keep the aspect of applying `nullable=false` ?

Comment: Why do you want to disable validation?

Comment: @DavidG It's just a thought because the I have FluentValidation and it doesn't work with the Required DataAnnotation validating as well. But I still want the nullable=false. I know there is FluentApi but I think it isn't practical